# Как реализовать игровую валюту в телеграмм боте с библиотекой aiogram

Tags: python, разработка-игр, aiogram

Я начал писать игру в телеграмм боте через библиотеку `aiogram`, но для этой игры нужна игровая валюта, но я не знаю как её сделать. Я поискал в интернете, но не нашёл. Могли бы, вы, подсказать как это сделать. Ещё желательно, чтобы она сохранялась при перезапуске или вообще хранилась в .txt файле и там уже изменялась по надобности

Comment: Всмысле? Игровая валюта это же просто строчка в бд, разве нет?

Answer (score -1):

Есть модуль **[pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)** для хранения python обьектов в файлах(**сериализация**). Можно при запуске скрипта каждый раз проверять есть ли файл сохранения, если есть то считывать данные от туда и работать с ними до закрытия программы. Потом перед закрытием программы сохранять новые данные в файл.

```
import pickle
from os.path import exists

file_path = 'save_file' # путь к файлу сохранения

scores = dict() # словарь валюты(это может быть и не словарь)

if exists(file_path):
    # если есть файл сохранения загружаем данные
    scores = pickle.load(open(file_path, 'rb'))

# делаем что то с данными
scores['User12'] = 100
scores['SomePerson42'] = 50

# сохраняем новые данные обратно в файл
pickle.dump(scores, open(file_path, 'wb'))
```

Есть варант с базой данных, но придеться писать sql запросы поэтому думаю вам будет лучше сначала попробовать сериализацию.